# Javascript send href without clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm not sure if this is possible. I have a link like this

```
<a id="addCart" href="http://mydomain.foxycart.com/cart?name=test-product&price=10.00">Add to Cart</a>
```

This link, when clicked, sends the values to a json shopping cart on another server.

However I have a situation where I need to send similar values with this href link but without being clicked. e.g:

```
$('.name').each(function() {
    while (y < data.products.length-1) {
        if($(this).text() === data.products[x].name) {
            $('.price').eq(x).text(data.products[x].price);
            //href here!
        }
        x++;
        y++;
    }
    x=0;
    y=0;
});
```

I need to pass this href:

```
href="http://mydomain.foxycart.com/cart?value=true"
```

in the //href here! part above, without being clicked. I hope I'm making sense with my request. Is there a method to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: you need to tell one event atleast. Do you want to send it on mouse over, document ready or something!!

Comment: I just want to pass that href to the remote server if a condition is true

Comment: Do you need to be able to handle a response from the server? (And why is the question tagged "json"? You're not using json in the code shown, you're just using a traditional query string.)

Comment: @user2028856: How is that condition set and evaluated? Where ever you do that you make the call i.e: $.post/$.ajax/$.get, etc...

Comment: No, just post a value to the server. Cause whatever value I pass to the server is stored in a json object which later I need to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your problem is **yes** you can do it. However it requires from you to have access in the other side in order to modify the script in a way that accepts cross site requests. However you should be very careful with this because implies many security risks.

It is possible to do it this way:

**the link:**

```
<a href="http://mydomain.foxycart.com/cart?value=true" id="send_without_click">There is a link</a>
```

**Javascript/JQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a_handler = "#send_without_click";
    var $a = $(a_handler);
    var a_url = $a.attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: a_url,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {
            href: a_url
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            //Do something before send. If not just remove the "beforeSend" part...
        },
        success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //the responseData is what you will get as response from the server
            var value = responseData.someKey;
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('POST failed.');
        }
    });
});
```

In the server side your page who receives the post request must have some headers defined in order to be able to receive the AJAX call. This will allow to your script to make cross domain POST, GET and OPTIONS. Here is an example in PHP:

example file **cart.php**

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) {
    case 'http://from.com': case 'https://from.com':
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
    break;
}
```

All the above will follow this sequence:

1. Browser sends a **OPTIONS** method to the server. This is a "security" measure by the browser to see if the server allows cross site (whatever allows the server) posts/requests
2. Then the server responds with an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" telling the browser that allows you to POST|GET|ORIGIN if the request is originated from "http://from.com" or the secure form of "https://from.com".
3. Since the server is okay, the browser will make the POST request you asked for.

***Notes**

- It is good practice to have your client set the content type it is sending - so you'll need to allow that as well.
- The server will make 2 requests per operation
- Security implications are raising. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' is kind of dangerous.
- This wont work on very old browsers and possibly on mobile browsers.
- Always return the headers above and not just the **OPTION** requests.

#### EDIT:

Also i found a way to retrieve data if you know that a website (external) is using *JSONP* Ajax.

```
//JSON format:
{"name":"stackoverflow","id":5}
//JSONP format:
func({"name":"stackoverflow","id":5});
```

If you know that *example.com* is serving JSON files that look like JSONP, then you can use code like this to retrieve it, even if you are not on the *example.com* domain:

```
function func(json){
    alert(json.name);
}
var elm = document.createElement("script");
elm.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
elm.src = "http://example.com/jsonp";
document.body.appendChild(elm);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 window.location="http://mydomain.foxycart.com/cart?value=true";
```

**OR**

```
window.location.href="http://mydomain.foxycart.com/cart?value=true";
```

however this takes browser to the location if this is what you want

OR without leaving the page.. you can use ajax.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post', 
    url: 'http://mydomain.foxycart.com/cart?value=true',
    success: function(data) {
        // do your stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to redirect. I'm assuming OP only wants to execute a post/get to that href passing some values for storage.

Comment: I think the specified url is to a different domain. Won't the OP have cross-domain errors trying to do a plain ajax post?

Answer (score 0):

This will call the url without leaving the site you are on.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://mydomain.foxycart.com/cart?value=true',
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

I'm not 100% sure if you can call another domain, in case the javascript runs on a different one. So maybe you need to do:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/cart?value=true',
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

Comment: What about cross-domain issues? I get the impression (from "another server") that the OP doesn't want to post to the same place the page loaded from...

Comment: This can be solved I think if you change the type to "type:'post'" and configure the other server you call to accept the params as POST and not GET Params.

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = "...";

if($(this).text() === data.products[x].name) {
   $('.price').eq(x).text(data.products[x].price);

   //put this code
   $.ajax(href, function(resp) {
        //do something
   });
}
```

Comment: What does the ajax part perform? Is this the same as the other post or get methods or does this just load the href call?

Comment: It is same as $.post. Only difference is it sends the parameters using get method. You can use the resp to do whatever you want. If the response is some html data. You can do `$("div").html(resp)`

Answer (score 0):

Have I got this wrong, but aren't you just trying to do

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mydomain.foxycart.com/cart/",
    type: "get",
    data: { value : true }
});
```

Comment: It is, however I'm getting not found when I run the code. Could it be a cross domain issue? However the normal href link works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the Url's Href values using JSON.parse and do your processing with your loop etc.Prevent the click of the link as well...

Check this out on here http://jsfiddle.net/RKc6f/

```
$(function() {
    $("#addCart").on('click', function(e) { 
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var urlParams = url.substring(url.indexOf("?")+1);

        var myProduct = (JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(urlParams.replace(/&/g, "\",\"").replace(/=/g,"\":\"")) + '"}'));
        console.log(myProduct.name);
        console.log(myProduct.price);
        //do the processing    
        e.preventDefault();//preven going to other page   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late but since no answer is accepted, and noone mentioned yet:
You can also use a virtual image element and pass your url to it's src causing a get request that have no CORS restrictions. Along these lines:

```
var getter = document.createElement('img');
getter.src = href; //url got from the $('#addCart') element or whatever you need
```